# Usercontrol .ascx variable access

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, compiler-errors

What should be done to solve the problem of access?

Markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Header.ascx.cs" Inherits="Version_2.Themes.Anatema.Header" %>

<%= deneme %>
```

Code:

```
namespace Version_2.Themes.Anatema
{
    public partial class Header : UserControl
    {
        public string deneme = "asd";
    }
}
```

Error:

> The name 'deneme' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Visual Studio does show that error message sometimes. Have you tried building the solution again?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="user.ascx.cs" Inherits="user" %>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">
<%=test%>
</asp:Label>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
using System;

public partial class user : System.Web.UI.UserControl{

public string test = "This is a test";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    this.DataBind();

}
}
```